# when i import database in mysql on server then getting a collations error message

Tags: mysql, database, importerror, collation

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_commentmeta` (
`meta_id` bigint( 20 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
`comment_id` bigint( 20 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`meta_key` varchar( 255 ) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL ,
`meta_value` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> ## 1273 - Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci'

Comment: you need to change your collation. Something like `ALTER TABLE myTable  CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci` ... then redo your export/import

Comment: Thanks Its Working Now

Comment: Sounds like you have an old version of MySQL?  utf8mb4 came with 5.5.3; I don't know when that collation came.

Answer (score 0):

Open your .sql file in notepad and find this

```
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
```

and change

```
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
```

Second option is:

1) Click the "Export" tab for the database

2) Click the "Custom" radio button

3) Go the section titled "Format-specific options" and change the drop down for "Database system or older MySQL server to maximize output compatibility with:" from NONE to MYSQL40.

4) Scroll to the bottom and click "GO".

Comment: You can not edit 7gb sql file.